# Pacakge builder using powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, package

I have a bunch of PowerShell scripts and some dependency modules and other files. I am looking to build a package (can be .exe, .msi anything) where I can copy that package file on the target server and just execute it to extract all files. Please help.
The target servers are in disconnected state

Comment: Set up a [local repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-local-psrepositories), upload your modules to it with `Publish-Module` and then have the target server pull it from the repo with `Install-Module`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, the target servers are in a disconnected state. We need to manually copy it to it. The build will contain other txt files and folders as well.